# Call delegate on main thread from asynchronous task

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

This seems simple enough... wanting to do this in .NET 3.5 (CF compatible if possible).

I want to call a function, and pass it a callback function that it fires upon completion. How is this done?

Example code:

```
public static void downloadTemplateDataAsync(int officeID, int? workbookID, TemplateType templateType, int? templateID, TemplateRequestDelegate callback)
{
    Template t = null;
    System.Threading.Thread callingThread = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread;
    new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
    {
        t = downloadTemplateData(officeID, workbookID, templateType, templateID);

        // Dispatch callback
        callback.Invoke(t);
    }).Start();
 }
```

Comment: Your form / control should have the `Invoke` method. Pass it the callback delegate, and it should execute it on the UI thread. Oh, and you should be able to do things like asynchronous I/O without creating new threads anyway, just use an asynchronous API to do the download.

Comment: What doesn't work in your code?

Comment: This application doesn't have a 'UI Thread'.

Comment: if it doesn't have a GUI, then what you want to achieve by calling the delegate in main thread?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the question in the comments, why do you want to execute the delegate on the main thread? That said, if you insist it can be done in a couple of ways, both of which require you to implement some infrastructure for your main thread to allow it.

The simplest to understand is to write some explicit code to coordinate. For example, taking your original code:

```
public static void downloadTemplateDataAsync(int officeID, int? workbookID, TemplateType templateType, int? templateID, TemplateRequestDelegate callback)
{
    Template t = null;
    object o = new object();
    System.Threading.Thread callingThread = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread;
    new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
    {
        t = downloadTemplateData(officeID, workbookID, templateType, templateID);

        // Signal completion
        lock (o) Monitor.Pulse(o);
    }).Start();

    lock (o) Monitor.Wait(o);
    callback.Invoke(t);
    }
 }
```

Note that this will *block* your main thread while the other thread does its work. This is pretty much always the wrong thing to do, but does literally accomplish your request.

If you want the main thread to continue working on something else, then it needs to be implemented to do that something else while also periodically checking for completion of your task, at which point it would invoke the delegate. WinForms and WPF programs have a message-pumping loop that is also used for this purpose. If you want the same behavior in your non-GUI program, you'll have to reinvent that particular wheel.

On the bright side, if you do that and at the same time implement a custom SynchronizationContext that works with your implementation, then you get the other cross-thread features of .NET essentially for free. On the not-so-bright side, doing all that is a *lot* of work.

Are you really really sure you need this behavior? If you explain in more detail what you're actually trying to accomplish, you might get a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info... what I'm doing is creating an abstraction layer. These functions could be used by a GUI application, a command line application, whatever. I want the user of the API to be able to call the Async function, and pass a callback to it. Much like how you can use AsyncCallback/IAsyncResult with SQL Server and Http Requests. I can't find much information online about how to do your own AsyncCallback/IAsyncResult.

Comment: I don't know SQL Server specifically, but IAsyncResult in general doesn't do anything special wrt invoking delegates on the original thread. Those callbacks are usually invoked on whatever worker thread was used to complete the operation. I don't know what's supported in CF, but pre-.NET 4.5 (async/await) you can use SynchronizationContext directly or BackgroundWorker (which uses SynchronizationContext) to abstract this sort of thing. Where it matters (GUI program), the delegate will be invoked on the correct thread, otherwise it will just be invoked on the current thread.